# SWIG Not Accepting Wrapped Objects For Pointer Parameters

Tags: java, c++, pointers, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to wrap some C++ code for Java. I have a C++ class (`BitVector`) which SWIG wraps just fine.

My problem is that I have also have a method on another class that takes a parameter of type `const BitVector& ranges`, but SWIG is wrapping that parameter as a `SWIGTYPE_p_BitVector`.

I get two different SWIG wrapper files generated: a `BitVector.java`, and a `SWIGTYPE_p_BitVector.java`. When I go to call the method from Java (actually Scala), and present a `BitVector` object, my Scala compiler complains that I'm passing a `BitVector` where it wants a `SWIGTYPE_p_BitVector`.

Is SWIG supposed to produce code automatically to allow me to pass a wrapped object when a const reference or pointer is expected? Is there some sort of typemap that I could construct to pull the `BitVector.swigCPtr` field out?

All I can find on Google is instructions on how to deal with the case of pointers to primitive types. There are typemaps in `typemaps.i` for that that let you pass e.g. a Java `int` when the underlying C function wants an `int*` and is only going to read it, but I can't find anything similar for the SWIG-generated wrapper types.

Comment: Short answer is yes SWIG normally handles this just fine, it should not create a separate class for the const reference version. Something is wrong with the .i file perhaps, can you post the portion of .i file that shows includes and bitvector defs? Have you tried some of the test files that come with SWIG, the simplest examples will show that this should work and should compile fine.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I've solved this. Yes, SWIG is supposed to allow you to pass a wrapped class to a function expecting a reference or pointer to such a class. It turns out that the problem I was having here was a namespacing issue.

`BitVector` is really defined as `CSA::BitVector`, and gets `using`'d by the file in which the method taking a `const BitVector&` resides. This `using` directive did not make it into my SWIG file, so SWIG thought `BitVector` and `CSA::BitVector` were two different types, and wrapped them both.

I solved the problem by including `using CSA::BitVector` in the .i file. It wasn't getting picked up from a transitive include.